# Getting minutes from 24 hour time?

Tags: java, math

I will start with an example: time is 20:00 (2000) and I want to find how many minutes its been since 09:00 (0900), I tried using mod of 60 but this gave me an off time.

Example:

```
Elapsed time between 1610 1700
1700-1610 = 90, this is obviously wrong
(1700-1610)%60 = 30,
```

90-30 equals 60, but the answer should be 50. I'm very confused with what I should be doing, how would I go about dealing with this in java? Thanks!

Comment: Use duration/period and respective parser from joda library.

Comment: I've rolled back to the question. If you want to delete your question there's a seperate button for that. Be ware though that deleting downvoted questions may get you in some trouble when it comes to being able to ask new questions. If you need more assistance in updating/changing your question you can always ask [at meta.so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Convert hours to minutes.

```
1700 hours = 17*60 minutes
1610 hours = 16*60 minutes + 10 minutes
```

to find out the difference, simple subtraction will do the job

```
17*60 - 16*60 - 10
```

Update:

Assuming user enters in 0000 (hhmm) format, you can simply split by size

```
//psuedo code
String data = userInput;
int hours = Integer.parseInt(data.split(0,2));
int mins = Intger.parseInt(data.split(2,4));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would there be a way to split this up if it was entered from a user and I had no idea on the times though? However they would always follow the XXXX format

Comment: @user3488485 - String.valueOf(intXXXX).subString() will help you.

Comment: You miss a `;`at the end of `String data = userInput`

Comment: @CladClad, it's pseudo code. anyway I corrected it :)

Answer (score 1):

You mixing two representations of the time

- 13:50
- 1350 (minutes)

13:50 is 13 hours and 50 minutes, but 1350 is 1350/60 = 22 hours and 1350%60 = 30 minutes

Before you can add, subtract, multiply or divide time you have to convert it to number. In your case:

Elapsed time between 16:10 17:00

```
16:10 = 16*60+10 = 970
17:00 = 17*60+00 = 1020

17:00 - 16:10 = 1020 - 970 = 50
```

In Java you could write:

```
public int minutesFromTime(String time) {
    String [] parts = time.split(":");
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    return hours * 60 + minutes;
}
```

Then

```
System.out.println("Difference is "
   + (minutesFromTime("17:00") - minutesFromTime("16:10"))
   + " minutes");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like this, you are confusing hour and minute as the same unit in your way to do this.
You should separate hour and minute to get the good answer

for example:

```
String time1 = "1700";
int hour1 = Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(0,2));
int minute1 = Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(2,4));
```

From `int` to `String` to parse

```
 int timeInt = 1715;
 String time1 = ""+timeInt;
 int hour1 = Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(0,2));
 int minute1 = Integer.parseInt(time1.substring(2,4));
```

Or staying in `int`

```
 int timeInt = 1715;
 int hour = timeInt / 100;
 int min = timeInt - hour*100;
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow did not think of. As I just said above how could I split up and integer after the second digit? As the input will always be ABCD and since I need to deal with them seperately i would need it to be AB and CD.
Thanks!

Comment: No prob ;) I updated to parse the string for you

Comment: Thanks again. Assuming the input is an int not a string, is this still possible? Thanks!

Comment: of course ;) there are two ways to do this i will update my code to expain

Answer (score 0):

To convert your 24-hour time to minutes you need to determine hours and minutes:

```
int hours = time / 100;
int minutes = time % 100;
```

And then calculate minutes since midnight:

```
int minutesSinceMidnight = (hours * 60) + minutes;
```

You can subtract the minutesSinceMidnight for both times to arrive at the time difference in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

you are dealing with time (60 min), so you can't directly use the math functions (10 base).
So I suggest that you convert your data to Date and then deal with it.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "HHmm");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("1610");
Date date2 = dateFormat.parse("1700");
long diff = date2.getTime() - date.getTime();
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple example should do the job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String after = "2000";
    String before = "0900";
    int hours = (parseInt(after) - parseInt(before)) / 100;
    int minutes = (parseInt(after) % 100) - (parseInt(before) % 100) % 60;
    if (minutes < 0) minutes += 60;
    System.out.printf("Minutes passed from %s to %s are %d\n", before, after, hours * 60 + minutes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume user will always input in XXXX (hhmm) format you can try using this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter first time value: ");
    int firstTime = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter second time value: ");
    int secondTime = userInput.nextInt();

    int hoursFirst = (int)(firstTime/100);
    int minutesFirst = firstTime%100;

    int hoursSecond = (int)(secondTime/100);
    int minutesSecond = secondTime%100;

    int difference = Math.abs((hoursSecond - hoursFirst - 1) * 60 + (60 - minutesFirst) + minutesSecond);

    System.out.println("Difference between " + hoursFirst + ":" + minutesFirst
            + " and " + hoursSecond + ":" + minutesSecond + " is " + difference + " minutes.");

}
```

**Output example:**

```
Enter first time value: 1820
Enter second time value: 1610
Difference between 18:20 and 16:10 is 130 minutes.
```